# excel: if error then return "n/a" but if cell blank return nothing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I change the formula below to handle for empty cells?

```
=IFERROR('[KPI.xls]Sheet1'!F192, "N/A")
```

It corrects returns "N/A" when theres an error but it returns a 0 when the cell is blank.

I found many threads on this issue but couldn't get any to work.

Comment: What did you want it to return if it were blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted it to return "BLANK" if it were blank, you can use an if statement.

```
=IF(ISBLANK('[KPI.xls]Sheet1'!F192),"BLANK",IFERROR('[KPI.xls]Sheet1'!F192,"N/A"))
```

You can substitute in "" or whatever you like for "BLANK".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return N/A for blanks then

```
IF(or(ISERROR('[KPI.xls]Sheet1'!F192),ISBLANK('[KPI.xls]Sheet1'!F192)), "N/A")
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer depends on what you trying to return. If you are returning a text value that may be blank and want to avoid the **0** then append a zero-length string. The cell will not be truly blank (a cell with a formula never is); it will contain a zero-length string instead of a zero.

```
=IFERROR('[KPI.xls]Sheet1'!F192&"", "N/A")
'alternate that makes inserting formula via VBA a little easier
=IFERROR('[KPI.xls]Sheet1'!F192&TEXT(,), "N/A")
```

However, if you are trying to return a number then you have effectively converted your numerical value into text-that-looks-like-a-number and this is generally not a desired result.